# How to flip Y-axis in GLSL shader before gl_FragColor = texture2D(*,*);

Tags: opengl, glsl, processing

I need to flip my textures upside-down in shaders before applying perspective transformations. I modified **vertTexCoord** in **vert.glsl**, but I don't know where to use it in **swap.glsl**. The way to do it like

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, vertTexCoord );
```

does not work, because I also need the texture to be modified in perspective.

vert.glsl:

```
#define PROCESSING_COLOR_SHADER

uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat4 texMatrix;

attribute vec4 vertex;
attribute vec4 color;
attribute vec2 texCoord;

varying vec4 vertColor;
varying vec4 vertTexCoord;

void main() {
  gl_Position = transform * vertex;

  vertColor = color;
  vertTexCoord = texMatrix * vec4(texCoord, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

swap.glsl:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif

// General parameters
uniform sampler2D from;
uniform sampler2D to;
uniform float progress;
uniform vec2 resolution;

uniform float reflection;
uniform float perspective;
uniform float depth;

varying vec4 vertColor;
varying vec4 vertTexCoord;

const vec4 black = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
const vec2 boundMin = vec2(0.0, 0.0);
const vec2 boundMax = vec2(1.0, 1.0);

bool inBounds (vec2 p) {
  return all(lessThan(boundMin, p)) && all(lessThan(p, boundMax));
}

vec2 project (vec2 p) {
  return p * vec2(1.0, -1.2) + vec2(0.0, -0.02);
}

vec4 bgColor (vec2 p, vec2 pfr, vec2 pto) {
  vec4 c = black;
  pfr = project(pfr);
  if (inBounds(pfr)) {
    c += mix(black, texture2D(from, pfr), reflection * mix(1.0, 0.0, pfr.y));
  }
  pto = project(pto);
  if (inBounds(pto)) {
    c += mix(black, texture2D(to, pto), reflection * mix(1.0, 0.0, pto.y));
  }
  return c;
}

void main() {
  vec2 p = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution.xy;  
  vec2 pfr, pto = vec2(-1.);

  float size = mix(1.0, depth, progress);
  float persp = perspective * progress;
  pfr = (p + vec2(-0.0, -0.5)) * vec2(size/(1.0-perspective*progress), size/(1.0-size*persp*p.x)) + vec2(0.0, 0.5);

  size = mix(1.0, depth, 1.-progress);
  persp = perspective * (1.-progress);
  pto = (p + vec2(-1.0, -0.5)) * vec2(size/(1.0-perspective*(1.0-progress)), size/(1.0-size*persp*(0.5-p.x))) + vec2(1.0, 0.5);

  bool fromOver = progress < 0.5;

  if (fromOver) {
    if (inBounds(pfr)) {
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(from, pfr);
    }
    else if (inBounds(pto)) {
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(to, pto);
    }
    else {
      gl_FragColor = bgColor(p, pfr, pto);
    }
  }
  else {
    if (inBounds(pto)) {
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(to, pto);
    }
    else if (inBounds(pfr)) {
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(from, pfr);
    }
    else {
      gl_FragColor = bgColor(p, pfr, pto);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does texMatrix do?

Comment: "There is a new uniform in the vertex shader called **texMatrix**, which rescales the texture coordinates for each vertex (passed in the additional attribute texCoord), to take into account texture inversion along the Y-axis (as Processing's vertical axis is inverted with respect to OpenGL's)", as written at https://processing.org/tutorials/pshader/

Answer (score 6):

You sample the texture at

```
(u,v)
```

If you want to flip the Y-axis, just sample at

```
(u, 1.0f -v)
```

So your updated `main` will look like:

```
void main() {
  gl_Position = transform * vertex;

  vertColor = color;
  newTCoord = texCoord;
  newTCoord.y = 1.0 - newTCoord.y;
  vertTexCoord = vec4(newTCoord, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: My vertTexCoord  is already flipped upside-down with help of texMatrix (possible with Processing). The problem is how to apply it to gl_FragColor after or before perspective transformations in swap.glsl

Comment: gl_Position is what OpenGL uses to figure out what pixels to interpolate and draw. Per-vertex attributes like your vertexTexCoord are interpolated as well. I don't know why you would be applying a perspective transformation to your texture coordinate.

Comment: I suppose it wasn't clear. Swap.glsl does photo transition like this: http://transitions.glsl.io/transition/2a3f2e907e1c0a152e60 

The problem is that my photos are upside-down. And I can't modify gl_FragColor, because it is used by those transitions. I need a way to flip the texture before transition modifications.